# Button with a image, is possible?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am develop an `UWP` app and I want a button with a image, but I dont know how I make this. This is possible?

I want a button that has an image, or an image where it is possible to click on it!

I have tried several ways, and I dont know! I am using `XAML` and `C#`, in Visual Studio 2015

Comment: What *did* you try? Post your affords and where exactly they didn´t work. Otherwise you´ll get probably many answers that show you just the way you allready tried out.

Answer (score 2):

you can use Source attribute to Image control. you can try some thing like this

> ```
> <Button Grid.Column="0" Height="39" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Padding="0" BorderThickness="0">
>         <Image Source="location/img.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
>   </Button>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Xaml` you can find out that `Button` has attribute called `Content` which basically can store any kind of control inside.

`<Button Content="<defaultly you put a string in here>"/>`

But if you want to display some other type of content inside you can use something like this :

```
<Button >
    <Button.ContentTemplate> <!-- This will create new template for the button's content -->
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source=""/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Button.ContentTemplate>
</Button>
```

Or alternatively :

```
<Button >
    <Button.Content> <!-- This will create only the content control inside of this particular button object -->
        <Image Source="" />
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

Or use method posted by @Midhun Mundayadan

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MouseLeftButtonUp event handle of the image control to simulate button click

```
<Image MouseLeftButtonUp="Image_MouseLeftButtonUp" Source="img.png"/>
```